# You must supply a layout_height attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, debugging, xamarin

I've followed a tutorial using Xamarin and I'm facing a problem where it keeps display error :

> **Android.Views.InflateException:** 'Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_height attribute.'

I've checked my codes for so many times and all the layout_height's attribute are just fine. Can you guys help and notify me if there is other mistakes I didn't see?

Here is my XML file that I'm trying to debug:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/colorchoose"
    android:paddingBottom="10pt"
    android:paddingLeft="10pt"
    android:paddingRight="10pt"
    android:paddingTop="10pt"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:id="@+id/txtlogin"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPasswordLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="Forget Password ?    "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF007F"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
    <Button
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#ffca"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtlogin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:hint="Scan PFNo"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my @drawable/colorchoose xml file:
it only contain the color reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#ffff"
          android:endColor="#ffac"
          android:angle="45"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: @drawable/colorchoose only containts the color reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
          android:startColor="#ffff"
          android:endColor="#ffac"
          android:angle="45"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>

```

Comment: Check the dimens in the xml. Check if they're missing dp. For padding, dimens are provided in pt

Comment: yes sir, I paste it wrongly just now in the previous comment. The code is in my edited post. The error point to my Layout_height but I still can't find them.

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText have not layout_height

Comment: yes, thank you. I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add height here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Cool! I had a similar problem. It is only unclear why IDE did not issue any warnings. In any such case, it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `height` attribute here:

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
```